# Rails - Check if model is modulized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to check for any namespace in a model?

i.e this is what I would be looking for

```
Foo::Bar.modulized? = true
Bar.modulized? = false
```

The check is for any namespace not for a particular module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Foo::Bar.ancestors.select {|o| o.class == Module }.include?(Foo)
```

or

```
Foo::Bar.included_modules.include?(Foo)
```

To check if the Model has any namespace or not you can do this

```
Foo::Bar.parent == Foo #=> true
```

or simply

```
Foo::Bar.parent.is_a? Module #=> true
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: hm, for me `MyMod::MyClass.ancestors.select {|o| o.class == Module }.include?(MyMod) # => false`

Comment: Thanks RSB, but I should have been more specific. I am looking to check if a model has any namespace not a particular one.

Comment: `Foo::Bar.parent.is_a? Module` works great thanks RSB

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.name.include?('ActiveRecord::') # => true
```

To check if model is modulized with any module, just do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.name.include?('::')
```

But, be aware that it'll return true for inner classes:

```
class Main
  class Inner
  end
end

clazz = Main::Inner
clazz.name.include?('::')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to check for any modules not just a particular one. But that gives me an idea, this would work `ActiveRecord::Base.name.include("::") # => true` I can't think of it causing any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such method, but you can use Module::nesting to implement it, for instance if you have a nested class:

```
module A
  class B
    puts Module.nesting.inspect
  end
end
```

The output of the previous code is: `[A::B, B]`

If your class is not nested:

```
class C
   puts Module.nesting.inspect
end
```

The output will be: `[C]`

So, you can create a module with the modulized? class method:

-Create a file called active_record_extension.rb in the lib directory.

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def modulized?
      Module.nesting.size > 1
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

Create a file in the config/initializers directory called extensions.rb and add the following line to the file:

```
require "active_record_extension"
```